What are Blender equivalents to Softimage constraints?
Thank you for taking the time to read this. I've been struggling to get my shoulder armor for my Mega Man X project to work with an IK system. I stumbled upon a blogpost that potentially has some clues surrounding this, but they are using softimage, and the two main contraints that they use is the "Lookat" and "Up Vector" constraints. The "Lookat" seems like the Damped Track or Track To, but "Up Vector" has me stumped, and I can't seem to find what would be the Blender equivalent of that Softimage constraint, and their set up is based off of those two contraints.
The blogpost in question: https://polycount.com/discussion/200175/rigging-a-spaulder-an-easy-way-a-simple-way-to-rig-shoulder-armor

From what I can tell, reading your link:
A "lookat" is indeed a Track To constraint.
The "up vector" is not a constraint at all; it is the up axis of the Track To constraint.  The idea is that the up axis depends upon the orientation of the chest.
I can offer one way to achieve the same thing in Blender.  (There are probably multiple ways, but I don't use a track to for much myself.)  You can set the track to constraint to use "target Z" for the up vector:

This one is set to use the target's +Z axis as the up vector.  If we want that vector to point at the chest, as in your link, then we can give the target bone a damped track (track +Z) targeting the chest bone:

